# Efficient reduction of a list in python

Tags: python, algorithm, list, memory-efficient

So I have a list of 85 items. I would like to continually reduce this list in half (essentially a binary search on the items) -- my question is then, what is the most efficient way to reduce the list? A list comprehension would continually create copies of the list which is not ideal. I would like in-place removal of ranges of my list until I am left with one element.

I'm not sure if this is relevant but I'm using collections.deque instead of a standard list. They probably work the same way more or less though so I doubt this matters.

Comment: Please post the code.  It's not clear what you mean by `reduce`.  Python has a built-in `reduce()` function, but your question seems unrelated.  Please provide some code to explain what you mean.

Comment: Do you mean "reduce" in the functional sense, of combining adjacent items? Or do you just mean deleting them? If the latter, on what basis are items removed?

Comment: If you post your code at codereview.stackexchange.com you'll get a lot of people who can suggest ways to improve the speed. I'm not sure what you are doing, but with a better idea (such as by seeing the code) it sounds like a technique can be constructed that avoids "reducing" the list at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a mere 85 items, truthfully, almost any method you want to use would be more than fast enough. Don't optimize prematurely.

That said, depending on what you're actually doing, a `list` may be faster than a `deque`. A `deque` is faster for adding and removing items at either end, but it doesn't support slicing.

With a list, if you want to copy or delete a contiguous range of items (say, the first 42) you can do this with a slice. Assuming half the list is eliminated at each pass, copying items to a new list would be slower on average than deleting items from the existing list (deleting requires moving the half of the list that's not being deleted "leftward" in memory, which would be about the same time cost as copying the other half, but you won't always need to do this; deleting the latter half of a list won't need to move anything).

To do this with a `deque` efficiently, you would want to `pop()` or `popleft()` the items rather than slicing them (lots of attribute access and method calls, which are relatively expensive in Python), and you'd have to write the loop that controls the operation in Python, which will be slower than the native slice operation.

Since you said it's basically a binary search, it is probably actually fastest to simply find the item you want to keep without modifying the original container at all, and then return a new container holding that single item. A `list` is going to be faster for this than a `deque` since you will be doing a lot of accessing items by index. To do this in a `deque` will require Python to follow the linked list from the beginning each time you access an item, while accessing an item by index is a simple, fast calculation for a `list`.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing what you said with binary search.

Answer (score 1):

`collections.deque` is implemented via a linked list, hence binary search would be *much* slower than a linear search. Rethink your approach.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that this is what you really need but:

```
x = range(100)
while len(x) > 1:
    if condition:
        x = x[:int(len(x)/2)]
    else:
        x = x[int(len(x)/2):]
```

Comment: The // operator forces integer division eg. `len(x) // 2` is pretty much equivalent to `int(len(x)/2)`. The type of is that which would be returned by coerce. That is `3 // 2.0` equals 1.0

Answer (score 1):

1. 85 items are not even worth thinking about. Computers are fast, really.
2. Why would you delete ranges from the list, instead of simply picking the one result?
3. If there is a good reason why you cant do (2): Keep the original list and change two indices only: The start and end index of the sublist you're looking at.

Answer (score 0):

On a previous question I compared a number of techniques for removing a list of items given a predicate. (That is, I have a function which returns True or False for whether to keep a particular item.) As I recall using a list comprehension was the fastest. The fact is, copying is really really cheap.

The only thing that you can do to improve the speed depends on which items you are removing. But you haven't indicated anything about that so I can't suggest anything.

Comment: List comprehension is not cheaper because copying is cheap (although that's true), list comprehension is cheap because list comprehension does the looping on C level, it pretty much bypass half of python looping mechanism.

Comment: @Lie Ryan, right. But the copying is why most people and the OP think its more expensive. But copying is much cheaper then most people think.